# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD><STYLE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Code I am using for parssing JSON Values .

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json ="";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.i("JSON Parser", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Actvity class code

```
    private static final String TAG_UserLoginsResult = "UserLoginsResult";
private static final String TAG_BRANCH_ID = "BRANCH_ID";
private static final String TAG_USER_NAME = "USER_NAME";
private static final String TAG_User_ID = "User_ID";
private static final String TAG_msg = "msg";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray loginsResult = null;
String url = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /*
     * try { String URL = URLEncoder.encode(url1, "utf-8"); } catch
     * (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
     * block e1.printStackTrace(); }
     */
    /*
     * try{ String url =
     * "http://etosxmldev.ctdi.com/WS/WCF/AVAYA-MOBILE-    SERVICE/Service.svc/UserLogins"
     * + URLEncoder.encode("?","UTF-8") + "LoginId" +
     * URLEncoder.encode("=","UTF-8") + "samalorp" +
     * URLEncoder.encode("&","UTF-8") + "passWord" +
     * URLEncoder.encode("=","UTF-8") + "pass"; }catch (Exception e) { //
     * TODO: handle exception }
     */
    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    // getting JSON string from URL
    // http://etosxmldev.ctdi.com/WS/WCF/AVAYA-MOBILE-SERVICE/Service.svc/UserLogins?LoginId=samalorp&passWord=pass
    JSONObject json = jParser
            .getJSONFromUrl("http://etosxmldev.ctdi.com/WS/WCF/AVAYA-MOBILE-SERVICE/Service.svc/UserLogins");
    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        loginsResult = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UserLoginsResult);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < loginsResult.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = loginsResult.getJSONObject(i);

            String BRANCH_ID = c.getString(TAG_BRANCH_ID);
            String USER_NAME = c.getString(TAG_USER_NAME);
            String User_ID = c.getString(TAG_User_ID);
            String msg = c.getString(TAG_msg);
            System.out.println("===========>>>" + BRANCH_ID);
            System.out.println("===========>>>" + USER_NAME);
            System.out.println("===========>>>" + User_ID);
            System.out.println("===========>>>" + msg);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_BRANCH_ID, BRANCH_ID);
            map.put(TAG_USER_NAME, USER_NAME);
            map.put(TAG_User_ID, User_ID);
            map.put(TAG_msg, msg);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);

            // Intent i2 = new Intent(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.this,
            // otherActivity.class);
            // startActivity(i2);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It JSON Values are valid according to JSONLInt.

Json Values are

```
  {
    "UserLoginsResult": [
      {
        "BRANCH_ID": "R28",
        "USER_NAME": "saranya",
        "User_ID": "5677",
        "msg": null
     }
  ]
 }
```

used various option even for url encoding .Not be able to find the solution.new in android please give some idea.I know there are many question on like this.tried the solution given there but not worked for me.

```
    09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): <HTML><HEAD><STYLE type="text/css">#content{     FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT:    0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}</STYLE>
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): <TITLE>Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): <DIV id="content">
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): <P class="heading1">Service</P>
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): <BR/>
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): <P class="intro">Method not allowed.</P>
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): </DIV>
09-09 09:03:37.956: I/JSON Parser(266): </BODY></HTML>
09-09 09:03:37.966: E/JSON Parser(266): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <HTML><HEAD><STYLE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-09 09:03:37.993: D/AndroidRuntime(266): Shutting down VM
09-09 09:03:37.993: W/dalvikvm(266): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.example.testapp.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:66)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 09:03:38.006: E/AndroidRuntime(266):  at com.example.testapp.AndroidJSONParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.java:66)

Comment: This is the first time I am Dealing with JSON web service.Please Help me Give some suggestion.

Comment: So what is on line 66?

Comment: You can help yourself researching this site. Lots of related posts here at the right sidebar, same error...

Comment: when i tried to debug the main exception occur on this linetry {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

Comment: try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    } on line 66.

Comment: you are getting non json response. You are getting HTML page from server response.

Comment: But when i tried the same url on browser it gives jSOn result.

Comment: I am not getting the things please explain properly.

Comment: so that means the server is OK.  Why are you setting the BufferedReader size to 8?  If you are getting a NPE then your inputstream reading is failing.

Comment: Also why do you need newlines?  Maybe just read the whole inputstream in

Comment: variable is values are not null while debugging.what I should have to do.I have followed some tutorial.Just Becoz I am doing it first time.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I feel there is issue with variable references . Somehow its getting messed up. Please check that. Because your server returns correct JSON formatted data. Then there is less chance to get HTML tags in response. So check references once more.

Answer (score 1):

in your pasrser you build a JSON formatted string and pass it to be a JSON object

```
 try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

unfortunately the string is not JSON formatted and it fall in the exception thus the whole method returns null, and in your activity you call

```
JSONObject json = jParser
            .getJSONFromUrl("http://etosxmldev.ctdi.com/WS/WCF/AVAYA-MOBILE-SERVICE/Service.svc/UserLogins");
    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        loginsResult = json.getJSONArray(TAG_UserLoginsResult);
....
}
```

while your json  is null so it will fall in that catch block,
my suggestion recheck your JSON data and here is a good [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

**EDIT**
you should set the header to define that you are requiring json

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

```
// Making HTTP request
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
```

after that you add

```
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "JSON");
```

Comment: I HAVE CHECKED MY JSON DATA WITH THE SAME LINK =====VALID JSON

Comment: what do you get printed out when you call json = sb.toString(); Log.i("JSON Parser", json);can you post it again? in you question i see html got printed, is it possible you didnt link to the correct JSON file? "http://etosxmldev.ctdi.com/WS/WCF/AVAYA-MOBILE-SERVICE/Service.svc/UserLogins"

Comment: <TITLE>Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><P class="heading1">Service</P><P class="intro">Method not allowed.</P></BODY></HTML>

Comment: see? thats not a valid JSON formatted string, check the link again if it was correct it would print exact JSON lines {
    "UserLoginsResult": [
      {
        "BRANCH_ID": "R28",
        "USER_NAME": "saranya",
        "User_ID": "5677",
        "msg": null
     }
  ]
 }

Comment: what should do can you suggest some thing becoz when i run the url it gives json values.Can u suggest the line of code i should add.

Comment: so now you send a request and dont get JSON you should google that and refer to comments on your question

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String response="";

        try{
             String url="your ulr";
             response = sendRequest(url);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

        return response;
    }






//String Method to fetech data from server
public String sendRequest(String url) {
    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpParams httpParameters = client.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream ips = response.getEntity().getContent();

        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,
                "UTF-8"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s;
        while (true) {
            s = buf.readLine();
            if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
                break;
            sb.append(s);

        }
        buf.close();
        ips.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

Just used this method to fetch the valued for api.just permission on Manifest.xml for internel
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading in your response 8 bytes at a time and appending a newline to each 8 bytes.

as in

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "utf-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
```

Remove these two problems and it should work.

Comment: when I have changed the things as u have said error log gives Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.

Comment: But yours was 8 bytes.  Are you still having troubles?

Comment: Can you show the exact string you are getting back.  Did you remove the appending of the newline charachter?

Comment: <TITLE>Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><P class="heading1">Service</P><P class="intro">Method not allowed.</P></BODY></HTML>  in variable name sb final string .